# How to force order of execution?

Tags: swift3

I have the following class and need to ensure the caller first calls `init()`:

```
class MyClass: NSObject {
    static var myArray:[String] = []

    init() {
       //load array
    }
}

//then flow from caller should be
MyClass.init()
let someItem = MyClass.items[2]
```

However, the caller doesn't have to call `init()` and in that case will get an empty array. Is there a way to force calling `init()` first? Or some way to do it implicitly without creating a function to retrieve the array?

I'd like the caller syntax to remain `MyClass.items[x]`. That's why I don't want to do a function.

Comment: This seems like a really fragile design. Why should a static property be dependant on an initializer?!

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? There is probably a good solution for your problem, but not with the requirements given.